# How to count the number of times 1s predicted by a classifier for a particular instance

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Suppose I have a following lists of list containing labels predicted by a 3 classifier of same type

```
List = [[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1]]
```

How can I get the following?

```
List1 =[0,1,1,0]
```

which are labels that are predicted by most of the classifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` the lists together and get the most common element from each tuple.

```
arr = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
[max(set(x), key=x.count) for x in zip(*arr)]
# [0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Or, using `pandas`, convert the list of lists to a `DataFrame` and get `mode` along the columns

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(arr).mode().iloc[0,:].tolist()
# [0, 1, 1, 0]
```